# Vue div text is not dynamically updating

Tags: vue.js, binding

I have a div element:

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

But each time data is updated (I verify that with console.log), text in the div is not changing. Do you know how to change the text in the div dynamically as data changes

Comment: could you post your whole code and functionalities

Answer (score 2):

Vue does not actively look for any moustache syntax on your page and replaces it. It only controls what you tell it to (the template).

To tell Vue to control a particular template, you have to instantiate Vue with it.

Basic example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

// this instantiates Vue in the element with id="myTemplate"
new Vue({
  el: '#myTemplate',
  data: () => ({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Contents of `#myTemplate` are parsed as Vue template -->
<div id="myTemplate">
  <h2>Inside Vue template: {{foo}}</h2>
  <input v-model="foo">
</div>

<h2>Outside of Vue template: {{foo}}</h2>
```

Also note `data` is a reserved name in a Vue instance. It expects either an object or a function returning an object. Any property defined on that object at compile time is ***reactive*** out of the box. So you could say `data` is a reactive wrapper for the Vue instance. All its properties are available in the template and you don't have to prefix them with `data.`.

Therefore, if you really want to use `data` as a name in template, you have to define a `data` property inside `data`. (i.e: `data: () => ({ data: { foo: 'bar'}})` and use it in template as `{{data.foo}}`.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but the thing is that I use router view ( which is not I problem I think ), because on opening the page, the correct data is displayed (using the Mustache syntax {{}}). The thing is, when I update the data, it doesn't visually change. But it does, when I first open the page. This is my concern.

Comment: Are you sure you're providing the `data` inside the component that gets rendered at that route? Provide a [mcve] (I suggest using codesandbox.io) and I'll have a look.

Comment: Okay, I will send the link in 5 minutes

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-field-e0hox?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `$("but1")` retuns a function. You probably meant `$("#but1")`? Not to mention you should use `@click` rather than binding via jQuery. Vue is in charge of those DOM elements and you can't rely on the fact they'll be there on next render. Mixing jQuery with Vue like that will most likely provide a lot of subtle bugs and you'll end up with less hair. Don't take my word on it. Give it a few years. Here's [Vue events docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

Comment: Two more issues with your sandbox: you're not running `clickListener`, so those bindings are never done. Run it in `mounted()`. Secondly, the function bound has to be an arrow function so `this` points to the Vue instance, not to the `click()` function. [Here it is](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-breeze-hmm1z), fixed. But again, I strongly advise against binding via jQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, and fixing it as well! Have a good day :)